# php multiple session name or sub-session name?

Tags: php, session, cookies

my script currect have two session called

```
$_SESSION['mypic']
```

and

```
$_SESSION['mypicsrc']
```

can I combine this two to one session and sub-session?
like this:

```
$_SESSION['mypic']
$_SESSION['mypic']['src']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $_SESSION global is an array that will only store strings. If you want to store an array inside a $_SESSION var you have to serialize it first

```
$data = array( 'src' => '' );
$_SESSION['mypic'] = serialize($data);
```

then to get it back out you have to deserialize

```
$data = deserialize($_SESSION['mypic']);
```

However, you should store your data in a database and then store an id or reference to that particular record in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you only have one session there, with the values stored in $_SESSION.

You can change them like any other variable;

```
$_SESSION['mypic']['src'] = $_SESSION['mypicsrc'];
```